# How to pass a DynamicArray in c++ builder

Tags: c++builder

I'm using C++Builder XE4 with the VCL Win32 platform. I am tring to setup a method that will take a DynamicArray of TPoint as an argument. Below is from my .hpp file for a standard VCL Win32 Form. My declaration for CalcPolygonDetail() is generating the error message:  "Error in module NewForm: Incorrect method declaration in class TForm3_cpp" The problem is the argument DynamicArray  MyPoints, Can someone show how to setup this declaration correctly. Thanks.

```
#ifndef NewFormH
#define NewFormH
//----
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include "AdvSpin.hpp"
#include <Vcl.ComCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Mask.hpp>


DynamicArray<TPoint> MyPoints;


//------------
class TForm3_cpp : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
TImage *Image1;
TLabel *Label2;

----break----

int __fastcall CalcPolygonDetail(DynamicArray<TPoint>  MyPoints, bool UseScreenCoordinates );
```

.

Comment: Are you sure the code is like that? I've just tried this and it compiled fine. I'm on XE5 though. Now, what are you trying to do? you want a global variable called `MyPoints`, and later use inside the `CalcPolygonDetail` another variable with that same name? Or were you trying to define a type for an array of `TPoint`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple file compiles fine as a Console VCL App on XE5.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <tchar.h>

#include <stdio.h>

DynamicArray<System::Types::TPoint> MyPoints;

void __fastcall TestFunction(DynamicArray<System::Types::TPoint> MyPoints2, bool SomeOtherParam)
{
  // Do something with this.
  MyPoints = MyPoints2;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  DynamicArray<System::Types::TPoint> MyPoints3;
  TestFunction(MyPoints3, true);
    return 0;
}
```

Does this compiles fine for you? Maybe the problem lies somewhere else, because the DynamicArray definition seems correct. I would create a type instead:

```
typedef DynamicArray<System::Types::TPoint> TMyPoints;
```

Specially if you are going to use that kind of arrays in your code more than once. But as the example shows, even without this it should work.

Comment: I used your solution with C++B_XE4 and win7. I am finding C++B_XE4 and win8 has some bugs. I will stick with win7 for this project. Thanks.